# With which NativeScript variant can I develop on Windows for iOS and Android?

Tags: nativescript

With which subcategory between Angular, Vue, Plain TypeScript, PlainJavaScript, React or Svelte can I develop simultaneously for both operating systems on Windows? Or would you prefer VM?

Asked NS Support

Comment: You can not develop iOS application on Windows, thats restriction form Apple. You could use Cloud builds as a workaround. VM is also an option but it could be terribly slow. All the frameworks (subcategory as you say), are supported for convenience so the developer can pickup something he is most familiar with, the output is going to be same.